# Configure VS to only build for a specific Target for multiple Targets project (MAUI)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, maui

I have a habit of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> during development to make sure my changes are valid. However, for a MAUI project, pressing that combination results in multiple platforms being built like this:

[image]

It takes a very long time for it to finish, and cancelling the Build makes Intellisense going nuts everywhere.

I know that when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, the build is very quickly because only the platform I am running it on is being compiled. Is there anyway to temporarily disable building the binary for other platforms? I still need to support them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the `<TargetFrameworks>` entries in your csproj file. This is the default given by one of the project templates:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
<!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
<!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
```

This will compile for

- Android
- IOS
- MacOS
- Windows (but only if you're compiling from a Windows computer)
- NOT Tizen

Just comment out what you don't want to do at the moment.

Comment: Comment it out is a great idea! I can easily switch between platforms as I need as well.

Comment: Btw this solution would wreck our Source Control when each member would change the config accordingly. Is there a better way to configure it with an external file so we can ignore it? Thanks.