# How to change a MSBuild Property outside of the csproj in Visual Studio so it doesn't get into Git/version control?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, msbuild

Following [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74595861/configure-vs-to-only-build-for-a-specific-target-for-multiple-targets-project-m), I want to change `TargetFrameworks` for each developer on their machine only. However, I cannot find anyway to modify it without pushing something into our Git source control. Assuming we have a dev who works on Android and one who works on iOS, how should we do that?

Currently I can use Environment Variable but changes are not applied until VS is restarted and cleaning the project always results in some strange error until the 2nd restart.

```xml
        <TargetFrameworks></TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$(MAUI_BUILD.Contains('win'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$(MAUI_BUILD.Contains('and'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$(MAUI_BUILD.Contains('ios'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$(MAUI_BUILD.Contains('mac'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$(MAUI_BUILD.Length)==0">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0;net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this? If possible, I'd like to have it to be project-specific. For example we may have a `TargetConfig.txt` file in our project folder for example and we add that file into our `.gitignore`. Or something like `project.Development.csproj` like `web.config` transformation would be great too.

Note that the solution need to work on VS for Mac as well though I think there's no difference between MSBuild on Windows and Mac.

UPDATE: somehow my environment variable workaround doesn't even work on MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.user` to your `.gitignore`. Add a file with the name of your project and the .user extension as a peer of the project file.

e.g.

```
project1\
  project1.csproj
  project1.csproj.user
```

Place the per-user customizations in the .user file.

See [Customize your build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2022).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need! I have no idea how I couldn't find it when Googling.

Comment: After testing for a while, I realized this doesn't work for MAUI projects because VS actively writes this file very often for this kind of project.